# Javascript library: load only those files you need

Tags: javascript, web-applications, dojo

We are developing a javascript component to be used in a JSF app and we're using Dojo.
The thing is we only need specific parts of the library and we'd like to only insert into our webapp the files/folders we use to accomplish our goal.

We could do this 'by hand' but in the future we might need to add other functionality from Dojo and then we will not know what resources we need -> I guess by this moment you realised we are no Dojo/js gurus.

Basically we are looking for a way to automate this process. We were thinking of getting a list of the dependencies and then create a small script to 'filter' the files.

Is this possible ? Have anyone tried this before ?
Thanks.

Comment: How can I accept or close or mark this question as 'solved' ?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting your request, but I think dojo does what you want out of the box.  Since the latest versions of dojo follow the Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) format, you use a global `require` function to describe what dependencies a specific block of code have, and only those modules are loaded.  An example from the [sitepen dojo intro](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/hello_dojo/):

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom){
    var greeting = dom.byId("greeting");
    greeting.innerHTML += " from Dojo!";
});
```

If you only want to have to to load a single `<script/>` tag, you'll want to look into the dojo builder. Using the [online build tool](http://build.dojotoolkit.org/) You can select what packages you want included into the dojo.js layer and it will bundle everything up into a zip file that includes dojo.js/dojo.js.uncompressed.js which contains dojo core in addition to the modules you selected.

Comment: Yeah but in this case I would only be declaring 'dojox/charting/Chart' and only use dojox/charting/Chart.js file in my webapp folder which will cause errors because Chart.js file uses other files by itself and those file use other files and so on. I need a way to find this whole 'tree' of dependencies.

Comment: @tartak: You should keep all the dojo files in your folder during development (preferably the non-minified versions, to ease debugging). If you want to minimise the number of files uploaded to the production server then you can just use the build system for that.

Comment: "... use the build system for that." This is exactly what we want. Do you have a suggestion for that ?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your use cases, You might want to take a look at the web builder (http://build.dojotoolkit.org/) or the dojo build intro (https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/build/buildSystem.html#build-buildsystem).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we did this by doing the following (just in case anyone will need this):

```
    * declare a JSF filter and map it to /js/* (all dojo resources are under /js folder, this may need to be modified to fit your folder structure); this way, all requests for a dojo resource will be filtered.
    * in the filter class, get all the requested files: (HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI() and write it line by line in a file: now you have all the needed resources.
    * parse that file with a script, line by line, and copy the files to another location -> build  the folder structure.
    * use the created files in your WebContent folder (or wherever you need it), you have a clean library -> you only deploy what you use.
```

Answer (score -2):

The web is littered with full-blown JavaScript libraries who say they will save your day and make your web development life much easier. You get encouraged to include these “mere 80 kb” libraries that is supposed to be the solution to all your needs, and practically make the web site work by itself. Needless to say, I’m not a big follower of JavaScript libraries,, especially since they almost always include lots of superfluous code, so I thought I’d put together a tiny library with only essential JavaScript functions.

The result of that is EJ – Essential JavaScript.

EJ consists of functions that I use all the time and they make writing JavaScript go faster and the result is being able to do work more efficiently. It is also about having the things you would write again and again for every web site you produce in one neat and tiny file instead, to be able to focus on the new things you need to address